# Getting CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException Error

Tags: android, cursor

Dear stackoverflowers,

I have a database inside my android application that i send to it a String and return a Cursor.
Here's the codes:

```
public Cursor listSearch(String phonename) {
        Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(SQLITE_AllPhones, new String[] { KEY_ROWID,
                KEY_OEM, KEY_PHONENAME, KEY_MODELNUMBER, KEY_AVAILABILITYDATE,
                KEY_URL, KEY_URL2, KEY_URL3, KEY_RELEASEDATE, KEY_SIM,
                KEY_ANDROID, KEY_COLORS, KEY_DIMENSIONS, KEY_WEIGHT,
                KEY_DISPLAYTYPE, KEY_DISPLAYSIZE, KEY_RESOLUTION, KEY_PPI,
                KEY_CARDSLOT, KEY_INTERNAL, KEY_CAMERA, KEY_CAMERAFLASH,
                KEY_FEATURES, KEY_VIDEO, KEY_FRONTCAMERA, KEY_CHIPSET, KEY_CPU,
                KEY_GPU, KEY_MEMORY, KEY_BATTERY }, null, null, null, null,
                null);

        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }

        String cursor = "Select * FROM AllPhonesTable WHERE phone_name = '"
                + phonename + "'";
        Log.e("cursor", cursor);
        mCursor = mDb.rawQuery(cursor, null);

        return mCursor;

    }
```

Then, i access that cursor from another class :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        gotBasket = BigSpecs.this.getIntent().getExtras();
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.specs);
        imageLoader = new com.androidarabia.lazylist.ImageLoader2(
                getApplicationContext());
        apd = new AllPhonesDatabase(this.getApplicationContext()).open();
        c = apd.listSearch(gotBasket.getString("phonename"));
        Log.d("cursor", "The Cursor Number" + c.getCount());

        initialize();
        setuptext();
    }
```

Then i do my work depending on the Cursor:

```
private void setuptext() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final String imageurl = c.getString(c
                .getColumnIndex(AllPhonesDatabase.KEY_URL));
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(imageurl, pic1);

        final String Releasedate = c.getString(c
                .getColumnIndex(AllPhonesDatabase.KEY_RELEASEDATE));
        releasedate.setText("" + Releasedate);
        final String Androidversion = c.getString(c
                .getColumnIndex(AllPhonesDatabase.KEY_ANDROID));
        androidversion.setText("" + Androidversion);
        final String Sim = c.getString(c
                .getColumnIndex(AllPhonesDatabase.KEY_SIM));
        tvsim.setText("" + Sim);
        final String Dimensions = c.getString(c
                .getColumnIndex(AllPhonesDatabase.KEY_DIMENSIONS));
        dimensions.setText("" + Dimensions);
        final String Weight = c.getString(c
                .getColumnIndex(AllPhonesDatabase.KEY_WEIGHT));
        weight.setText("" + Weight);
        final String Color = c.getString(c
                .getColumnIndex(AllPhonesDatabase.KEY_COLORS));
        color.setText("" + Color);
        final String Dt = c.getString(c
                .getColumnIndex(AllPhonesDatabase.KEY_DISPLAYTYPE));
        displaytype.setText("" + Dt);
        final String ds = c.getString(c
                .getColumnIndex(AllPhonesDatabase.KEY_DISPLAYSIZE));
        displaysize.setText("" + ds);
        final String dr = c.getString(c
                .getColumnIndex(AllPhonesDatabase.KEY_RESOLUTION));
        displayresolution.setText("" + dr);
        final String PPI = c.getString(c
                .getColumnIndex(AllPhonesDatabase.KEY_PPI));
        ppi.setText("" + PPI);
        final String cardSlot = c.getString(c
                .getColumnIndex(AllPhonesDatabase.KEY_CARDSLOT));
        cardslot.setText("" + cardSlot);
        final String INTERNAL = c.getString(c
                .getColumnIndex(AllPhonesDatabase.KEY_INTERNAL));
        internal.setText("" + INTERNAL);
        final String CR = c.getString(c
                .getColumnIndex(AllPhonesDatabase.KEY_CAMERA));
        cameraresolution.setText("" + CR);
        final String FLASH = c.getString(c
                .getColumnIndex(AllPhonesDatabase.KEY_CAMERAFLASH));
        flash.setText("" + FLASH);
        final String FEATURES = c.getString(c
                .getColumnIndex(AllPhonesDatabase.KEY_FEATURES));
        camerafeatures.setText("" + FEATURES);
        final String VIDEO = c.getString(c
                .getColumnIndex(AllPhonesDatabase.KEY_VIDEO));
        video.setText("" + VIDEO);
        final String FFC = c.getString(c
                .getColumnIndex(AllPhonesDatabase.KEY_FRONTCAMERA));
        frontfacingcamera.setText("" + FFC);
        final String CHIPSET = c.getString(c
                .getColumnIndex(AllPhonesDatabase.KEY_CHIPSET));
        chipset.setText("" + CHIPSET);
        final String CPU = c.getString(c
                .getColumnIndex(AllPhonesDatabase.KEY_CPU));
        cpu.setText("" + CPU);
        final String GPU = c.getString(c
                .getColumnIndex(AllPhonesDatabase.KEY_GPU));
        gpu.setText("" + GPU);
        final String Memory = c.getString(c
                .getColumnIndex(AllPhonesDatabase.KEY_MEMORY));
        ram.setText("" + Memory);
        final String BATTERY = c.getString(c
                .getColumnIndex(AllPhonesDatabase.KEY_BATTERY));
        battery.setText("" + BATTERY);

    }
```

Just some simple codes of getting the text from database and set it nothing much.
But i get this error!

```
08-19 19:18:17.591: E/AndroidRuntime(7902): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-19 19:18:17.591: E/AndroidRuntime(7902): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.androidarabia.phones/com.androidarabia.big.BigSpecs}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1
08-19 19:18:17.591: E/AndroidRuntime(7902):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2246)
08-19 19:18:17.591: E/AndroidRuntime(7902):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2296)
08-19 19:18:17.591: E/AndroidRuntime(7902):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:151)
08-19 19:18:17.591: E/AndroidRuntime(7902):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281)
08-19 19:18:17.591: E/AndroidRuntime(7902):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-19 19:18:17.591: E/AndroidRuntime(7902):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-19 19:18:17.591: E/AndroidRuntime(7902):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
08-19 19:18:17.591: E/AndroidRuntime(7902):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-19 19:18:17.591: E/AndroidRuntime(7902):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-19 19:18:17.591: E/AndroidRuntime(7902):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
08-19 19:18:17.591: E/AndroidRuntime(7902):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
08-19 19:18:17.591: E/AndroidRuntime(7902):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-19 19:18:17.591: E/AndroidRuntime(7902): Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1
08-19 19:18:17.591: E/AndroidRuntime(7902):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:424)
08-19 19:18:17.591: E/AndroidRuntime(7902):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
08-19 19:18:17.591: E/AndroidRuntime(7902):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
08-19 19:18:17.591: E/AndroidRuntime(7902):     at com.androidarabia.big.BigSpecs.setuptext(BigSpecs.java:62)
08-19 19:18:17.591: E/AndroidRuntime(7902):     at com.androidarabia.big.BigSpecs.onCreate(BigSpecs.java:50)
08-19 19:18:17.591: E/AndroidRuntime(7902):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5250)
08-19 19:18:17.591: E/AndroidRuntime(7902):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
08-19 19:18:17.591: E/AndroidRuntime(7902):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2210)
08-19 19:18:17.591: E/AndroidRuntime(7902):     ... 11 more
```

Thanks, your help will be much appreciated =)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call mCursor.moveToFirst() method after the query. Check if you do this after query near this line checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:424).

Answer (score 0):

You must move your cursor to the first row to read from it. You somewhat did that for the first query, but not for the second one (e.g. it is missing after `mCursor = mDb.rawQuery(cursor, null);`).

```
final Cursor cursor = /*...*/;
if (cursor.getCount() < 1){
  // handle empty cursors somehow, e.g. no results
  return;
}
cursor.moveToNext();
// or
cursor.moveToFirst();
```

Comment: @KingOmar please add your `onCreate` method.

Answer (score 0):

Check cursor before accessing data from it

```
If(cursor!=null && cursor.moveToFirst())
```